# My IIS 7 Management Console Connection Pane doesn't show any sites I have created

Tags: iis

When I open my IIS manager (IIS 7), it doesn't show any of the sites I have set up and created in the connection pane.

[image]

(names blacked out for privacy requirements) However, I need to see those sites in the Connection panel as I want to add a new virtual directory folder. Where do I find the setting to show the sites in the left hand "Connections" pane?

Comment: What version and edition of Windows? I presume you mean that the "Sites" node of the Connections tree view doesn't expand and is missing the expand hint (+) ?

Comment: Windows 10 and yes, it's the Sites node of the Connections Tree. I've already clicked on the "Sites" link in the picture I provided.

Comment: What "edition" of Windows 10, could be important.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit OS